# Nonlinear least squares curve fitting in R

Tags: r, least-squares

I am new to R (first time using it). and I am following this tutorial http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5254 to try to plot a curve and discover the function that best fits my data. So far I have tryed:

```
> xdata = c(1 ,5, 10, 20, 100)
> ydata = c(23.83333333, 210.3666667, 545.3666667, 1756.866667, 38595.7)
> plot(xdata,ydata)
```

So I get this:

[image]

Then I try:

```
> p1 = 1
> p2 = 0.2
> fit = nls(ydata ~ xdata^2, start=list(p1=p1,p2=p2))
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `nls` function does not automatically include coefficients for all of your parameters in the model. You must explicitly include them in the formula. I'm not exactly sure where you wanted `p1` and `p2` to be included in the model from your description

```
p1 <- 1
p2 <- 0.2
fit <- nls(ydata ~ p1+p2*xdata^2, start=list(p1=p1,p2=p2))
fit

# Nonlinear regression model
#   model: ydata ~ p1 + p2 * xdata^2
#    data: parent.frame()
#      p1      p2 
# 127.216   3.847 
#  residual sum-of-squares: 21037
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.774e-08
```

but at least in this form this is still a linear model. You can get the same fit with

```
fit2 <- lm(ydata ~ I(xdata^2))
fit2

# Call:
# lm(formula = ydata ~ I(xdata^2))
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)   I(xdata^2)  
#     127.216        3.847
```

Comment: How can I plot the curve?

Comment: Plotting is a completely separate issue. But if you have a fitted model (either `fit` or `fit2`), you can use something like `xs<-seq(min(xdata), max(xdata), length.out=100); plot(xdata,ydata); lines(xs, predict(fit, data.frame(xdata=xs)))`.

Comment: The fitted values are already in the fit-object: `fitted(fit)` or `fit$m$fitted`. Only need to use predict if you are supplying a newdata argument.

Comment: @BondedDust If you just used the fitted values here, you wouldn't get much of a curve. I am using predict to estimate the curve in between observed x values.

Comment: In fit2 example the equation that describes my results would be: y=127.216 + 3.847*x^2     ?

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, you can include Senor O solution within `ggplot2` framework to get a plot of the smoothed solution and check the solution graphically:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat,aes(x=xdata,y=ydata)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method="nls", formula=y ~ p1+p2*x^2, se=FALSE, 
               start=list(p1=p1,p2=p2))
```

[image]

Comment: @fredcrs you're going in circles there buddy

Comment: You can use R markdown in R studio to knit HTML or Word that will print all the codes and their outputs together with the plots

Answer (score 4):

You have no parameters in your formula. You need to include them however you see fit:

```
nls(ydata ~ p1 * xdata^2 + p2, start=list(p1=p1,p2=p2))
```